# formatting title in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I want to include a `<br />` tag in the joomla title. I can see that this tag is not recognized. How can I make it to include a break in the title?

Comment: You may be approaching a certain problem in the wrong way with this solution, could you give a bit more information as to why you want to do this? Is it because of styling on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with an addon such as Nonumber.nl's rereplacer. You could - in theory - insert an unusual word in your title, such as 'breakbreak', then set the plugin to replace that specific text with a 
 tag.

Like others though - I question then need for this.